# Flutter / Mac / AndroidStudio / Gradle / appbundle

Tags: flutter

I finally finished writing my application (Mac + AndroidStudio) and I only have green check on each of my files.

Finally ... I tried to launch the build appbundle by following the guidelines described on the Flutter website.

I have the impression to have done by Google .... I site the result on its search engine: Futter Beautful native apps in record time.

Ok for the beautiful native apps but for the record time ... it's only for writing?

Since I am not a pure coder, I can not build the appbundle. I spend my time doing research on the net and I see that I'm not the only one. Same on Stack Overflow.

Question (to you dear coder friends and possibly to them Google coders): Is there a clean and safe way to generate the appbundle?

(I had less trouble on my first app with xcode at the very beginning of the swift !!!)

Good luck to all. Thanks to Stack Overflow who sharing solutions ....

Answer (score 0):

type `flutter build appbundle` in terminal in your project directory

Comment: Thank Mikhail.
As I wrote in my post I did everything as described on the "deployment" page of Flutter until ... fluter build appbundle on my Terminal.
And I see on the web that it seems that many people have problems to deploy the appbundle; then I wonder: is there a clean and safe method?

Comment: This answer provides very little context

Answer (score 0):

sorry.

To precise :

Project flutter built with AndroidStudio on Mac OS Mojave.

All my Flutter files are validated in green in AndroidStudio.

I followed step by step the tutorial Flutter page to deploy my application to build the necessary file to Goole Play Store.

I only use url_launcher and flutter_localizations. The pubspec.yaml is up to date.

My app works great on my smartphone when I launch the app. from AndroidStudio.

Is it common that this is not enough for the launch of the build to be successful?